# Spring MVC with maven tomcat plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am using spring mvc first time and when I am hitting this url "http://localhost:8899/web-test/welcome.htm" I am getting exception (please find below)

I am using maven tomcat plugin for running this application

and server is starting properly

below is the my pom.xml

```html
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for compile only, your container should have this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>web-test</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8899</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

web.xml

```html
<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/app_context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

controller class is

```html
public class HelloWorldController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");
        model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

        return model;
    }

}
```

exception I am getting

```html
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)


java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:885)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

app_context.xml

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean name="/welcome.htm" class="com.cog.test.controller.HelloWorldController" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

what thing I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You missing `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml ` you haven't mapped your controller, for example check http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: Hi Vijendra try giving /*.htm in your url pattern

Comment: @SauliusNext thanks for reply, for the same I am using <init-param> for loading conext.

Comment: @Pradeep thanks for reply, but it is not working for me, I have tried for it